# wordpress deploying solution, ideas?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, deployment, aptana, web-deployment

I develop on a local machine a Wordpress site and I'm now looking for a mechanism to deploy it easy and fast. I'm thinking about a DEV environment (located on my local machine), a STAGING environment (a subdomain on the client page, maybe staging.example.com) and of course a LIVE environment (example.com)!

My current workaround:
As I work with Aptana I'm able to sync my changed files with the deploy mechanism the IDE provides. Exporting my local database, finding/replacing the permalinks and importing the whole thing - finish! To deploy live, I have to replace all staging files with the live files.

This should be easier! Is there anyone out there, having a better workflow?
I'm open and really excited about your ideas!

Thanks a lot
greetings

Answer (score 1):

Yep, it's frustrating and completely insane that Wordpress requires this process because they put absolute urls in the database.  I develop in a similar fashion using multiple staging sites for qa and client review.  After my first deployment with Wordpress I almost gave up on the platform entirely.  All of the solutions recommended by core developers and others simply didn't work.

So I wrote a plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/root-relative-urls/
that fixes the problem.  With this plugin you don't need to do a search & replace on your content.  No hosts file hacks, or dns tricks.  With my plugin you can access the site via IP address or Computername or any type of forwarded host.  And since it converts urls to root relative before they enter the database, you won't have to worry about them working between the different domain formats.  And since they don't hard-code the scheme (http/s) in the url you won't have to worry about the 520 or so bugs that were reported in the wordpress trac database if you use SSL.

It's a staple for any wordpress project I work on these days.  And I have written a couple other plugins to deal with idiosyncrasies that exist in the platform that you can check out here: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/profile/marcuspope

Hope that answers your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use Capistrano https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/ for all my deployment needs and it is really good solution. You can simply script anything and it just works.

It could work for your deployment scheme too.

Comment: capistrano seems to be a nice tool but a little bit to big for my purpose. is it possible to write an php script, which generates a DB dump, makes a find/replace over all urls, clears the live DB and imports the dump and finally copy the upload folder from staging to live....could that accomplish a php script?

Answer (score 0):

I also use Capistrano for both WordPress and Drupal deployments. I typically install modules locally for testing then push to test and production environments. For uploads, etc. I add custom tasks to manage syncing files stored in scm and those that are not. Here is a simple guide I put together.

http://www.celerify.com/deploy-wordpress-drupal-using-capistrano